# Generate SCP string

Tags: linux, shell, scp

Generally when I am copying files from a local instance to a server, I find it difficult to generate the SCP string for the server to copy the files. I need to execute the following three commands `whoami`, `ifconfig` & `pwd` and then copy the outputs of each of them to generate the SCP copy string.

Is there a better way to generate the copy string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following command works for me.

```
paste -d'@:' <(whoami;) <(ifconfig | awk -F':' '/inet addr/&&!/127.0.0.1/{split($2,_," ");print _[1]}') <(pwd)
```